# How can I integrate solr with a existin view?

Tags: views, search

I have a question on how to integrate a solr search page to an existing view, because I bought a theme and they have a great view for search in a specific content type and I want to add to that view facet filters and solr search core, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) What do you mean by "integrate", exactly?

Comment: Hi, I mean display the search results in a existing view

Comment: It depends exactly what you mean by that - if you mean can you automatically convert a Content-based View to a Search API-based View, then no, I don't believe so. They use completely different handlers behind the scenes, and the data types aren't compatible. If you mean can you create a new search-api View, then embed into the header/footer of your existing View, then yes, absolutely